# Background position and repeating

Tags: css

I'm trying to create faked transparent form fields that "show through" to the background which is a tiled image (which of course are "showing" through the numerous divs between the inputs and the page background). Here's where I'm at:

```
div#searchbox, div#mailing_list ul li.fields,div#product div.info input.text {
    border:1px solid #707070;
    background:url(../_images/fade_bg.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
input#search {
    background-position:-715px -163px;
}
input#name {
    background-position:-134px -888px;
}
input#duhlyh-duhlyh {
    background-position:-134px -926px;
}
```

Now, this works as expected except the background position property isn't doing anything. I can remove them, change them, nothing happens. I'm guessing that it has something to do with the fact it's a repeating background. The position values are the element offsets from the body where the background itself starts. Any way to line these up?

Comment: Can you show an example on something like http://jsfiddle.net ? Thanks.

Comment: There isn't any javascript involved. These fields are statically placed. They'll always be in the same spot. Pulled the offsets from jQuery offset(), but I don't need to use jQuery/js after I've gotten the values.

Comment: Javascript is only 1/3 of the features that JSFiddle is used for. :)

Comment: Good lord. Nevermind, total brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

`inputs` are very hard to style using css.

However, what you could try (works in Firefox) is to remove the background image from the inputs and give them a `background:transparent` so that the background of the parent shows through.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS nesting for this code

`input#search {
    background-position:-715px -163px;
}
input#name {
    background-position:-134px -888px;
}
input#duhlyh-duhlyh {
    background-position:-134px -926px;
}`

with their respective parent elements because sometimes what happens is some properties are overwritten. in that case you can use css nesting and make it work